# How to do Lookup Iteration

Tags: r

I have a dataset (example below) where each row is a separate entry of questionnaires for participants' appointments, and participants frequently give more than one entry. One column is the ID number, one is the entry timepoint, and value1/value2/value3 are values for the questionnaire or disease phenotype data. My hope is to iterate a lookup so that if one value for a given ID and entry timepoint is "NULL", then it looks for the same value at the next entry timepoint in order. Thus, the desired final output would have 1 row per ID with the earliest entry value that was recorded.

So far, I have been able to do this with XLOOKUP in Excel and given the size of the dataset and the number of entries it takes a very long time to make any other changes. Is there a way in R to write a function or with tidyverse to iterate this process through many value# columns?

Thanks for your time!

**Sample input**

```
| id | timepoint| value1 | value2| value3|
| -- | -------------- |--------------| --------------|--------------|
| 1| entry1|2019 |NULL |NULL |               
| 1| entry2|NULL |NULL |2 |
|2 | entry1|NULL |NULL |NULL |
|2 | entry2|NULL| 7| NULL|
|3 | entry1|NULL|NULL |10 |
|3 | entry2|2018 | 8| NULL|
|3 | entry3| 2018|NULL | NULL|
|3 | entry4| 2019|9| NULL|
|4 | entry1| 2020|3| NULL|
```

**Desired output**

```
| id | value1 | value2| value3|
| --------  |--------------| --------------|--------------|
| 1|2019 |NULL |2 |               
|2 |NULL |7 |NULL |
|3 |2018|8 |10 |
|4 | 2020| 3| NULL|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, you can't have `NULL` in a column, so I'll assume those values are standard missing values `NA`. This will collapse each ID to a single row, keeping the first non-NA value in each of the `value` columns:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("value"), \(x) {
    if(all(is.na(x))) NA else first(na.omit(x))
  }))
```